# How to apply inline css in Button using Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
const styles = {
    bgColor:{
        backgroudColor: '#f9a825'
    }
}

<Button color='primary' classes={fab:classes.bgColor} variant="fab" aria-label="Checkout"> Click Here </Button>
```

Here, I want to change the background-color. its applying, but  it giving priority to Theme css.

Answer (score 2):

1. The `classes` prop is applied incorrectly.
2. You shouldn't even use `classes` since you don't seem to inject any; you should use `style`.

```
<Button color="primary"
        style={styles.bgColor}
        variant="fab"
        aria-label="Checkout">
    Click Here
</Button>
```

---

If you indeed inject `classes` into you component, you use it like this:

```
<Button color="primary"
        classes={{ fab: classes.bgColor }}
        variant="fab"
        aria-label="Checkout">
    Click Here
</Button>
```